# Construct objects for client in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a simple registration system using Firebase as a backend. I am successfully authenticating users and writing to the database. I have an index of courses and users with the following structure:

```js
{
  courses: {  // index all the courses available
    key1: {
      title: "Course 1",
      desc: "This is a description string.",
      date: { 2018-01-01 12:00:00Z }
      members: {
        user1: true
        ...
      }
    }, 
    key2 { ... },
  },
  users: {    // track individual user registrations
    user1: {
      key1: true,
      ...
    },
    user2: { ... }
  }
}
```

I have a cloud function that watches for the user to add a course and it builds an array with the corresponding `courseId` that will look at the `courses` node to return the appropriate items.

```js
exports.listenForUserClasses = functions.database.ref('users/{userId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    var userCourses = [];
    var ref = functions.database.ref('users/{userId}');
    for(var i=0; i<ref.length; i++) {
      userCourses.push(ref[i])
    }
    console.log(userCourses); // an array of ids under the user's node
  });
```

So, my question has two parts:

1. How can I build the updated object when the page is loaded?
2. How do I return the function to the client script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:** From the client side you want to get the reference to the database path.  Then you want to call the **child_added** event.  Keep it in-memory, this will be called whenever one is add then you can update your UI.

```
var ref = db.ref("path/to/courses");
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    var newClass = snapshot.val();
});
```

If you are completely refreshing the page then you can always grab the data again from the database path by using the **value** option and calling `once`

**Questions 2:** You don't.  This is considered an asynchronous function.  If you wanted a response from the function then you would setup an HTTP trigger and wait for the response from that function.